# How did Ignis know about Nyx?

Tags: final-fantasy-xv

In *Episode Ignis*, when Ignis has the Ring of Lucii, after Ardyn warns him of the danger of putting on the ring, Ignis notes that a Glaive was able to use the ring.

From my understanding, the Ring of Lucii has always been worn by royalty with one exception being Nyx Ulric, one of the Kingsglaive (or Glaives for short) who in *Kingsglaive* had worn the ring and been able to use its power to fight General Glauca and awaken the Old Wall.

Yet Nyx using the Ring of Lucii happened during Insomnia's fall when Noctus's crew were out of the city heading to Altissia and had no knowledge of the events in it beyond that the Empire attacked and Noctus's father had been killed.

So how did Ignis know about Nyx having worn the Ring of Lucii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not something that is fully explained in great detail in any of the Final Fantasy XV media, which can result in a plot hole at face value. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/7k9axm/spoiler_how_did_ignis_know_about/) Reddit thread may shine some light on it though. According to the comments in the thread, this plot-hole might be the result a difference between the English dialog and the Japanese dialog.

The English dialog says

> I may not be of royal blood, but if a Glaive can harness its power, then so can I!

The Japanese dialog says

> I heard that a Kingsglaive sacrificed himself to use the power of the ring

However, it is not explained *how* Ignis heard about Nyx's usage of the Ring. Additional users from the Reddit thread say it may have been scratched content, oversight, or apart of the news channels that were covering the fall of Insomnia